# Show that expectation value is finite

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let's consider sequence of an independent random variables $X_n$ which has the same distribution and we know that for each $n$, $EX_n=0$ the problem is to show that $E\left|X_0X_1+X_1X_2+...+X_{n-1}X_n\right|< \infty$ for $n \ge 1$

My try:

$E|X_0X_1+X_1X_2+...+X_{n-1}X_n|\le E|X_0X_1|+...+E|X_{n-1}X_n|=n \cdot E|X_0X_1| = n\cdot EX_0^2$ but now I don't know how to show this is finite.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, since all your $X_n$ are independent then $E[X_0X_1]=E[X_0]E[X_1] = 0$

Comment: that's true but we have absolute value here, we don't know if $E|X_0|=0$

Comment: I misread that as a bracket...Even if we don't know that $E[|X_0|]=0$ I think you can prove that it is finite with this argument: $E[|X_0|] = E[X_0^+] + E[X_0^-] = 2E[X_0^-] $, but since $X_0$ is integrable its negative part is finite and then $E[|X_0|]<K$

Comment: Thanks. Btw I think there is a typo, should be $E|X_0|=-2E[X_0^-]$

Comment: $E[|X_0|] = E[X_0^+] + E[X_0^-] = (E[X_0^+] - E[X_0^-]) + 2E[X_0^-] = E[X_0] + 2E[X_0^-] =2E[X_0^-]$ , no ?

Comment: $E[X_0]=E[X_0^+]+E[X_0^-]$ and $E|X_0|=E[X_0^+]-E[X_0^-]$ in my opinion, $E[X_0^-]$ is nonpositive so that would imply that $E[|X_0|]=0$

Answer (score 3):

If $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is an independent sequence, so is the sequence $\left(\left|X_n\right|\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$. Since 
$$\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}X_jX_{j+1}      \right|\leqslant \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left|X_j\right|\left|X_{j+1}      \right|$$
and $\left|X_j\right|$ is independent of $\left|X_{j+1} \right|$ for any $j\in\left\{0,\dots,n-1\right\}$, we derive  that 
$$\mathbb E\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}X_jX_{j+1}      \right|\leqslant \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathbb E\left|X_j\right|\cdot \mathbb E\left|X_{j +1} \right|, $$
and the right hand side consists of finitely many finite terms.

Notice that we only need pairwise independence and the fact that all the $\left|X_n\right|$ have a finite expectation. In particular, the $X_n$ do not need to be centered.